# Apex Trigger is not working appropriately on mass updating records

Tags: apex, soql, salesforce1-app, date, salesforce-id

Hi friends i got a requirement to revenue loss field in case wth specific record type and condition and i need to update based on account and other object with lookup to account based on criteria.

When i edit manually case it's updating perfectly.When i try to do mass update with data loader is not working accurately and updating different value.

I didn't get point why it is happening

My apex trigger

```
if(Trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate) 
    {
        //It will call a static method called RevenueLoss in ARPUCases class.
        ARPUCases.RevenueLoss(Trigger.New);
    }
```

My Apex class

```
public static void RevenueLoss(List<Case> CaseTriggers) 
    {
        Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Customer_Order'].Id;
        List<Case> CaseIDs = new List<Case>();
        system.debug('Old Values'+CaseTriggers);
        for (Case s : CaseTriggers)
        {
            if(s.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && s.Case_Details__c =='Cancell' && s.Revenue_effective__c <> null) 
            {
                // Loop through and add caseId's to the list.
                CaseIDs.add(s);
            }
        }
        set<Id> CaseAccountIds = new set<Id>();
        List<Account> AccountInfo=new List<Account>();
        Integer DaysDifference=0,RevenueContract=0;
        List<Account> Accountstoupdate =new List<Account>();
        List<Zuora__Subscription__c> Subscription=new List<Zuora__Subscription__c>();
        for(Case c : caseTriggers)
        {
            // Loop through and add AccountId's to the list.
            CaseAccountIds.add(c.AccountId);
            system.debug('***TTT****'+CaseAccountIds);
        }
        AccountInfo=[Select Id,Revenue_Since__c from account where Id=:CaseAccountIds];
        Subscription=[SELECT Id,Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c FROM Zuora__Subscription__c WHERE Zuora__Account__c = :CaseAccountIds ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
        For(Account a:AccountInfo)
        {
        for(Zuora__Subscription__c sub:Subscription) 
        {
            for(Case cs:CaseIDs) 
            {
                System.debug('DATA in Revenue_effective Before '+ cs.Revenue_effective__c);
                if(sub.Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c <> null && cs.Revenue_effective__c <> null ) 
                {
                    DaysDifference=cs.Revenue_effective__c.daysBetween(sub.Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in Revenue_effective Before '+ cs.Revenue_effective__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c Before '+ sub.Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in DaysDifference Calculation '+ DaysDifference);
                }
                if(a.Revenue_Since__c <> null && cs.Contract_Term__c <> null) 
                {
                    RevenueContract=cs.Revenue_effective__c.daysBetween(a.Revenue_Since__c.addMonths((Integer)cs.Contract_Term__c));
                    System.debug('DATA in RevenueContract Calculation '+ RevenueContract);
                    System.debug('DATA in Revenue_effective Before '+ cs.Revenue_effective__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in the account '+ a.Revenue_Since__c);
                }
                if(DaysDifference>=RevenueContract) 
                {
                    cs.Revenue_Loss__c = (cs.Total_units_ordered__c)*DaysDifference;
                    System.debug('DATA in Revenue_Loss__c Days Difference Calculation '+ cs.Revenue_Loss__c);
                }
                else if(RevenueContract>DaysDifference) 
                {
                    cs.Revenue_Loss__c = (cs.Total_units_ordered__c)*RevenueContract;
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know where i missed it.

Comment: Can you turn on the debug logs and upload relevant information from the debug logs?

Comment: Hey @abhi. It's working perfect when i update or create manually even debug logs works fine.But when i do mass update it is not working appropriately and how can i share  debug logs logs for mass update like data loader

Comment: In your innermost for loop you are iterating over all Cases. Instead iterate only relevant Cases for specific account.

Comment: Two ways - 1> Keep developer console active and do the mass upload.
2> Turn on debug logs for the user and do the mass upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are not selecting the right Account (you are looping on all accounts of the trigger context and not the Accounts associated to the selected Cases)

Then you are using three nested "for loops" in an inappropriate way  (updating all case in every Subscriptioon loop, and for every Account loop!!)

I understood that you have to update the Case associated to the account and to Subscription and not all the cases of the Trigger context.

Here my suggestion using Maps:

```
public static void RevenueLoss(List<Case> CaseTriggers) 
    {
        Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Customer_Order'].Id;
        List<Case> CaseIDs = new List<Case>();
        system.debug('Old Values'+CaseTriggers);
        Set<Id> CaseAccountIds = new set<Id>();
        for (Case s : CaseTriggers)
        {
            if(s.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && s.Case_Details__c =='Cancell' && s.Revenue_effective__c <> null) 
            {
                // Loop through and add caseId's to the list.
                CaseIDs.add(s);
                // Loop through and add AccountId to the accountId Set
                CaseAccountIds.add(s.AccountId);
            }
        }

        Map<Id,Account> accountInfoMap=new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,Revenue_Since__c from account where Id=:CaseAccountIds]);
        Integer DaysDifference=0,RevenueContract=0;
        Map<Id,Zuora__Subscription__c> subscriptionByAccountMap= new Map<Id,Zuora__Subscription__c>();

        for(Zuora__Subscription__c subscription:[SELECT Id,Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c,Zuora__Account__c FROM Zuora__Subscription__c WHERE Zuora__Account__c = :CaseAccountIds ORDER BY CreatedDate]){
            subscriptionByAccountMap.put(subscription.Zuora__Account__c,subscription);
        }

        for(Case cs:CaseIDs) 
        {
            System.debug('DATA in Revenue_effective Before '+ cs.Revenue_effective__c);
            Account a = accountInfoMap.get(cs.AccountId);
            Zuora__Subscription__c sub = subscriptionByAccountMap.get(cs.AccountId);

            if(a!=null && sub!=null){
                //update case only if it is associated to an Account and a Subscription
                if(sub.Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c <> null && cs.Revenue_effective__c <> null ) 
                {
                    DaysDifference=cs.Revenue_effective__c.daysBetween(sub.Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in Revenue_effective Before '+ cs.Revenue_effective__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c Before '+ sub.Zuora__NextRenewalDate__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in DaysDifference Calculation '+ DaysDifference);
                }
                if(a.Revenue_Since__c <> null && cs.Contract_Term__c <> null) 
                {
                    RevenueContract=cs.Revenue_effective__c.daysBetween(a.Revenue_Since__c.addMonths((Integer)cs.Contract_Term__c));
                    System.debug('DATA in RevenueContract Calculation '+ RevenueContract);
                    System.debug('DATA in Revenue_effective Before '+ cs.Revenue_effective__c);
                    System.debug('DATA in the account '+ a.Revenue_Since__c);
                }
                if(DaysDifference>=RevenueContract) 
                {
                    cs.Revenue_Loss__c = (cs.Total_units_ordered__c)*DaysDifference;
                    System.debug('DATA in Revenue_Loss__c Days Difference Calculation '+ cs.Revenue_Loss__c);
                }
                else if(RevenueContract>DaysDifference) 
                {
                    cs.Revenue_Loss__c = (cs.Total_units_ordered__c)*RevenueContract;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Works like charm.........